# Reading SQL CLOB via a script

Tags: sql, plsql, clob

I have a lengthy (with about 1000 characters) `clob` object stored in a table. I need to read this value through a `bash` script. How can I do this?

I've tried using a normal `SELECT` query. But then the output comes as multiple lines. I cannot merge them as it does not produce the exact text in the database in special cases (e.g. if there is a space at the end of single line)

e.g.

```
abcd
efg
hijk
```

If I merged the lines with `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g;'`, this becomes `abcdefghijk` when the actual text is `abcdefg hijk`.

What is the best approach for doing what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a way around using the above method, I managed to do what I want using a different approach.

Since the space character was the problem, and since I am the one who is inserting those `clob`s, instead of inserting the text directly, I've first `base64` encoded the text and inserted the encoded text into the table.

I could use the same `SELECT` query after this. I had to perform a `base64` decode on the select output to get the original text.